# ToolStripButton Click issue

Tags: c#, focus, toolstrip

My Window Form has a Toolstrip, there're a few Toolstrip Buttons on it. I click one Toolstrip Button to bring a Dropdown Color dialog, the Color Dialog is showing, but I have to click the Dialog window twice to select a color (one click to gain focus, another click to select color). It is very annoying. I move the same code under a standard Button, the dropdown color dialog just need one click to select a color. How to solve the double clicking problem on this Toolstrip button? [image]

```
private void tsbShowDowndownColorDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Need to click twice to select a color
{            
    NativeColorPicker.DropDownControlManager _ColorPickerManager = new NativeColorPicker.DropDownControlManager(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + 6), new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));                  
        object objectValue = new ColorEditor().EditValue(_ColorPickerManager, ChoosenColor);
        if (objectValue != null && !_ColorPickerManager.Canceled)
        {
            ChoosenColor = (Color)objectValue;
        }  
}

    private void btnShowDowndownColorDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Normal!
    {                        
        NativeColorPicker.DropDownControlManager _ColorPickerManager = new NativeColorPicker.DropDownControlManager(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + 6), new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));            
            object objectValue = new ColorEditor().EditValue(_ColorPickerManager, ChoosenColor);
            if (objectValue != null && !_ColorPickerManager.Canceled)
            {
                ChoosenColor = (Color)objectValue;
            }  
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the focus programatically after opening the color dialog?

Comment: The Color dialog got focus because the keyboard are working (I can use keyboard to do selection)after popup. Only mouse has to click once then click another done the selection. I saw some software has the same problem.

Comment: I replace the Toolstrip button with Toolstrip split button (or insert a standard button on Toolstrip) then problem resolved. So, the root problem is on Toolstrip button's behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I replace the Toolstrip button with Toolstrip split button (or insert a standard button on Toolstrip) then problem resolved. But I haven't had a workaround on Toolstrip button, I just avoid to use Toolstrip button to bring out any popup windows.